# Instantiate google map object with a defined set of bounds?

Tags: api, google-maps

I want to create google map using a pre-defined set of bounds.

So instead of the usual:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));

map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0),5);
```

I want to do something like:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));

map.setBounds(new GLatLng(10,10), new GLatLng(20,20));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see below:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));    
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(10,10), new GLatLng(20,20));
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```